# Why does python 3 command run Python3.9 and not Python 3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip, module

I have python installed on my Mac. But when I execute some scripts I made, if they contain packages, it will give me a module not found error. That's because I execute my scripts via "python3 <script_name.py>". In order to execute the script and use all the packages I have installed (which are for version 3.10), I have to write "python3.10 <script_name.py>".

How come I have to deliberately write python3.10 before the script name? Why doesn't it use python3.10 as my default Python version?

python3 <script_name.py> gives a "module not found error" because all packages are installed for Python3.10, and python3 execute Python3.9.

UPDATE: FYI Python3.10 is located at /usr/local/bin/python3.10 and Python3.9 is lcocated at /usr/bin/python3

Comment: I would recommend using `pyenv` and/or virtual environments to manage what `python3` (or even simply `python` refers to), instead of file-system links. Even if you have multiple programs named `python3`, it's the value of your `PATH` variable that will determine which one gets found first during command lookup. (And that's exactly how activating a virtual environment works: it ensures that the virtual environment's `bin` directory appears earlier in your `PATH` than the global directories.)

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l $(which python3)`?

Comment: /usr/bin/python3

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you have multiple versions of python installed and Python 3.9 happens to be the global env...If you're starting, the environments can get complex so I recommend pyenv, it's really helpful.

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Here's the answer you're looking for:

Find where Python 3 is

```
$ which python3.10
/usr/local/bin/python3.10
```

Write alias in bash_profile

```
vi ~/.bash_profile  
alias python3='/usr/local/bin/python3.10'
```

Reload bash_profile

```
source ~/.bash_profile

$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.[whatever version you have here]
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I learned about pyenv and am considering using it on my Mac. But the second option could also be useful, because I think I need the bash_profile file for using pySpark. I don't have that file in my home dir, so I'm guessing I just need to make it myself? Is that the only way to get it?